# Round ImageView with blur when use Kingfisher3.1

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, kingfisher

I want to make a roundCorner for userAvatarImageView. At first, I used the common ways to UIImageView:

```
extension UIImageView {
    func makeRoundedCorners(_ radius: CGFloat) {
         self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
         self.layer.masksToBounds = true
   }
}
```

It was works for me. But I don't think this is a good way for tableViewCell. So, I used RoundCornerImageProcessor:

```
let roundProcessor = RoundCornerImageProcessor(cornerRadius: 15,
                                               targetSize: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))

userAvatarImageView.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: string),
                                    placeholder: UIImage(named: "placeholder"),
                                    options: [ .processor(roundProcessor)])
```

It can get a roundCorner, but the image was blur, not clearly. like this:

[image]

How can I handle this issue?

Comment: your imageview size is 30*30 ?

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya. Yes, What's the matter with that?

Comment: dont set target size for it just set your image view corner radius according to your image view frame.

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya，I have tried it. Even if I assign corner to 30, it also can't get a round imageview like above image. What's the reason? Could you give me more details? Thanks

Comment: I have some another solution for you that get original image from URL after getting original image just give corner radius to your imageview don't forgot to give cliptobound = true

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya，Thanks for you advice. But what's the difference like I did it to layer? self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
self.layer.masksToBounds = true

Comment: problem is with your image clearity . if you fetch small image from server and set in imageview so your image clearity is loss so get orignal image or image size like 500*500 and just give corner radious so your image clearity look in device

Answer (score 0):

The unit of image processor is pixel instead of point. If you are trying to set the image to a 30x30 point image view on a retina display (I guess you should need so), it means you need to resize it to 2x at least, which means 60x60.

And if you are also targeting an iPhone x Plus 3x display, you need 90x90.